# How can I adjust the position of my drop-down menu?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, navigation, position, submenu

I would like to adjust the positioning of my drop-down menus on my [navigation links](http://jeffreydowellphotography.com). I tried adjusting "nav .folder ul li a " but i couldn't get it to move. I would like to move its position down about 10px.

CSS:

```
body .main-nav li > a,
body .main-nav li > a:visited {
    color: #3b5998;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; }

#nav a:hover {
    border-top: solid 4px #b7c3e6;
    color: #b7c3e6;
 }

.header-alignment-left.header-navigation-split #topNav { position:absolute; right: 0px }

.logo-image #topNav nav li a { padding:4px 15px; line-height: 100% }

#nav a { border-top: 4px solid transparent }

#nav .subnav { margin-top: 4 }

#nav a { border-right:0px solid #3b5998; height: 20px }

#nav li:last-child a { border-right: 0 }

#topNav nav .folder ul li a {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out }

#header #topNav nav .folder ul li {
    padding: 0 24px 12px;
    position: relative; }

#header { margin-top: 20px !important }

#topNav { margin-top: 40px }

#nav .subnav ul { padding-bottom: 15px !important }

#nav .subnav ul { padding-top: 15px !important }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#topNav nav .folder .subnav` div has an absolute top of 100%.  If you change that to a px value (say 45px) you can move it.

```
#topNav nav .folder .subnav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
    left: 0px;
    background: #ffffff;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

EDIT: Ended up leaving the above below and adding

```
#topNav nav li.folder {
  height: 32px;
}
```

Comment: when the curser moves down to the submenu, it now disappears/ or disconnects from the hovering

Comment: It looks like you're using some library to create the menus.  Which one are you using?  We could hack the css, but it'd be better to work within the framework.

Comment: its a template based site from squarespace.com  All the code above is what i have added. Im not sure what you mean by library

Comment: Ok, I can't resist hacking the css :).  change the top back to 100% in the css above and add #topNam nav li.folder {height: 45px;}

Comment: actually 32px seems better

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36561/discussion-between-barbara-laird-and-jeff-dowell)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `margin-top: 10px;` to `nav .folder ul`

Answer (score 0):

add `margin-top: 10px;` to `#topNav nav .folder ul`